# AxMSTSCLib PerformanceFlags setting don't work

Tags: c#, performance, rdp

I'm trying to display an element of the standard Windows RDP client in my program.
Everything works well, but I cant set the performance setting (disable images, themes, etc), since this option is ignored, for any values.
Here is a description of possible values: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa381215(v=vs.85).aspx

```
namespace RDPClient
{
    class RdpConnector : AxMsRdpClient7NotSafeForScripting
    {
        public  void Connect(string ip, string user, string pass)
        {
            Server = ip;
            UserName = user;
            (GetOcx() as IMsTscNonScriptable).ClearTextPassword = pass;
            AdvancedSettings6.RDPPort = 3389;
            AdvancedSettings7.EnableCredSspSupport = true;
            AdvancedSettings7.PerformanceFlags |= 0x00000002; // for example, disable fullwindowdrag
            Connect();
        }
    }
}
```

Using:

```
    RdpConnector RDPConn;
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RDPConn = new RdpConnector();
        RDPConn.Size = new Size(1024, 768);
        RDPConn.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

        ClientSize = new Size(1280, 768);
        Controls.Add(RDPConn);

        RDPConn.Connect("1.2.3.4", "user", "pass");
    }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the value of `AdvancedSettings7.PerformanceFlags` before the `|=` call? What is the value after the call?

Comment: @mjwills before 0(default), after 2(my)

Comment: Does https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/c2af56f8-0655-456a-94c1-d2edb0c69281/disable-full-window-drag-in-2008-r2-remoteapp?forum=winserverTS help?

Comment: @mjwills No, I can set this(and other) performance settings from the standard client ("Experience" tab).

Comment: it seems that this is another bug in windows, and it is unlikely that it will ever be fixed :c

Comment: Did you read the link I suggested? Did you set Full window drag locally as well as on RDP?

Comment: You are probably testing this with a fast remote machine that does not require this feature to be dropped.

Comment: Yes, ive watched this link, but I rly can change this parameter when connecting from a standard rdp client. My OS - windows 10, server OS - windows server 2012, with all stock settings.

Comment: @Hans Passant In the mstsc on the "Experience" tab, I can off any tick, "Show window contents while while dragging" too, and this setting is applying when connecting, I see the result.

Answer (score 0):

you should set the property first：**NetworkConnectionType**. And What kind of value does not matter.

[See Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/termserv/imsrdpclientadvancedsettings7-networkconnectiontype)